# Cannot connect to the MySQL database server, there are error messages but I do not know what the problem is and how to solve it

Tags: mysql, installation

I get the below error messages and think that I have more than one problem:

[image]

The first one is common:

> mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)

and I want to solve it by

`chgrp -R mysql /usr/local/mysql/data && chown -R mysql /usr/local/mysql/data`

But I got another error message:

> chown: /usr/local/mysql/data/.DS_Store: Operation not permitted

I do not know how to solve these...

```
2020-09-12T04:15:42.843047Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 1012
2020-09-12T04:15:42.849049Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
2020-09-12T04:15:42.855324Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-09-12T04:15:42.855495Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

These are other error messages. Can anyone figure out the problem and the solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

File '/etc/mysql/var/​log-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13). Doesn't mean it's not there; Error 13 means "Permission denied" Which If there is no .index file, and no binlogs mysql will just start over from scratch Remove any files in that directory.
Option 1:

```
service mysqld stop
```

Copy the log files including the .index file to new location.

```
 cp mysql-bin.log* /path/to/binlogs
 cp mysql-bin.index /path/to/binlogs
```

Do Changes in the /etc/my.cnf file.

[mysqld]
log-bin=/path/to/newdirecory/mysql-bin

log-bin-index=/path/to/newdirectory/mysql-bin.index

```
service mysqld start
```

Option 2:

Use this utiltiy to relocate binary logs:

```
mysqlbinlogmove --binlog-dir=/server/data /new/binlog_dir
```

Comment: I use MacOS, seems some commands can not be execuated properly. By the way, could you please explain more on how to operate(like using xxx, typing xxx)? I am not professional so I am just so confused about all these stuffs. Thanks a lot.